# Eliminating the duplicate counts

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set of $k$ objects and assume that $n$ length strings are to be constructed, where $n \geq k$.

I want to count a set of $n$ length strings, with the following restrictions 
1. all $k$ objects should occur. 
2. remaining $n-k$ positions can be occupied by any of the $k$ objects.

I tried calculating, but could not generalize the formula. 
Corresponding to restriction 1. ${n \choose k} \cdot k!$ 
Corresponding to restriction 2. $k^{n-k}$

But the final formula is not  ${n \choose k} \cdot k! \cdot k^{n-k}$ as some strings are counted more than once. 
How should I eliminate the strings which are counted more than once.

In short : Find a number of $n$-element permutations of $k$-element set items where each of $k$ elements appears at least once, for $n>k$

Please help.

Comment: Shorter: you seek a number of $n$-element permutations of $k$-element set items where each of $k$ elements appears at least once, for $n>k$.

Comment: true, I will add this as note.

Comment: Unless I'm totally misunderstanding the question, this is just a version of the coupon collector's problem, and the number of strings of length $n$ on an alphabet of $k$ elements that have at least one instance of each alphabet element is just $k! \mathcal{S}_n^{(k)}$ where $\mathcal{S}_n^{(k)}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation. Also with this formula, $\sum \limits_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} \ast k!S^{(k)}_{n} = k^n$?

Comment: Because this formula should represent the set of all possible strings of length n derived from the alphabet set of size k.